# Issue installing Linux dual boot Legion 5 15IMH05H

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, system-installation, usb-installation

It has been days since I’m trying to install Linux on my laptop in dual boot , but Ubuntu tells me to disable RST. After getting to the BIOS, I can’t find the option to switch RST to Ahci. Could you help me please

https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/39/1ogc.jpg

https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/39/jg8z.jpg

https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=20/39/uq61.jpg

if you want more screenshot or informations, I will give it to you thank you

Comment: Do not know if it will help, was for Acer laptop with same problem.  Was said that ```ctrl s``` would show hidden features in bios.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and if SSD, the SSD firmware? Do you have your drives listed somewhere in your UEFI settings, not shown in screens you posted. And then what settings for the drives.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work

@oldfred yes I have updated all the components of my laptop

Comment: Would google show hidden bios options for (make and model) your computer.

Comment: I found on Google that there is no advanced bios on my laptop

Comment: You might have to find another Linux distro that will install with RST enabled.  Would try Linux Mint and/or Manjaro.

Comment: I tried Linux mint,manjaro,PopOs,Fedora but the problem is the same, my ssd is not detected

Comment: There is a slim chance of taking drives out and trying to install with another laptop make, but seems like installing Linux on that laptop is not possible yet.  Contact makers and see if they can help.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can install ubuntu with previous versions, example: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Then install as usual. We don't need to turn off Intel RST. After you have finish to install. Using terminal to upgrade your ubuntu from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
FYI when we install previous ubuntu version, ubuntu doesn't require to turn off Intel RST.

Best Regards

Giri